# Javascript XMLHttpRequest PHP returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I try to call a PHP file via `XMLHttpRequest()`
Thats works fine. 
But now I want to call this function to get an array as return, but I get `undefined`:

```
function getSomethingPHP(){
  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ...
  hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        var obj = JSON.parse(return_data);
        return obj["val"];  
  ...    
}

var test = getSomethingPHP();

console.log(test); // -> undefined
```

I removed something in `XMLHttpRequest();` because this works, but I don't understand why `console.log(test);` callback `undefined`
Does anyone have an idea or solution for this?

Comment: `getSomethingPHP` has no return statement

Comment: return obj["val"];

Comment: That is in the `onreadystatechange` function, not the `getSomethingPHP` function.

Comment: I understand, how to return `onreadystatechange` in `getSomethingPHP` ?

Comment: See the duplicate question.